Cannot connect docker ip from host
Hello i have create a container using the default network, i want to directly access the container through container ip like : <container_ip>:8088 . But i do not know why i cann't. I know i can access through localhost with -p but i want to access directly to container.
i have tried to create my network ,and also tried map the container to host network. Both them are not work.
docker network create my-bridge-network


I can ping between container to each other , but not about from host.

Direct connections to containers via their docker bridge network IPs does not work on Docker Desktop as docker engine is running inside a vm.

Oh so how i can use the direct connections

direct connections from host to container is not actually a supported docker feature, its an artifact of how bridge networks are implemented. As such, the supported/general way to connect to a container is via a published port on localhost: Docker Desktop takes care to bridge these from the moby vm to the host.
If you really need to address individual containers on the same port, then you need to run a linux vm yourself with docker engine installed and run your software there.

The container-private IP address is inaccessible on many common setups.  You never need to look it up.  If your Docker/host-OS setup doesn't allow you to reach it, then no Docker options will make it possible.
You can only reach the container-private IP address from the host if:

You're on a native-Linux system; and
You're using the Docker engine directly, not Docker Desktop; and
You're calling from the same system and not a different host.

In Docker Desktop and similar setups (Minikube-as-Docker, Podman on MacOS, ...) there is a Linux virtual machine involved.  The container-private IP addresses are local to the machine they're running on and aren't routable.  But in one of these VM-based setups, that's the VM, and the host system is "a different host" for purposes of the last rule above.
From the host system, if you need to reach a container, you need to use the docker run -p or Compose ports: option to publish a container port to the host.  The two port numbers don't need to match, and if you're worried about publishing the port to the network, you can restrict it to the local system.  (docker run -p 127.0.0.1:5555:5432 postgres runs a PostgreSQL container, accessible on port 5555, only from the local system.)  Between containers, you can use Docker networking to call a container by name without knowing its IP address directly.
